# ggplot() will not save files to folder

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a very simple question:

After my analysis on multiple files (in the folder), ggplot will not save each graph to my specified folder. However, the plot() function will.

```
png(paste0(myFiles[j], ".png"), units ="in", width=7, height=5, res=300)

df1 <- data.frame(MO, -log(GC1), -log(GC2))
colnames(df1) <- c("MO", "IPs -> DLPFc", "DLPFc -> IPs")

data1 <- melt(df1, id.vars = "MO", measure.vars = c("IPs -> DLPFc", "DLPFc -> IPs"))

ggplot(data1, aes(x = MO, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=variable, group=variable), size=2) + 
  labs(x = "Model Length (ms)", y = "-Log(P-Value)") + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3, col='green', size  = 1.5) + 
  theme(legend.position="none") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=15, angle=0), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=15, angle=0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,30), breaks = c(0, 3.0))

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 4):

Store the output of your `ggplot` call to a variable, then pass it to `ggsave`:

```
gg <- ggplot(...)
ggsave( paste0(myFiles[j], ".png"), gg, width=7, height=5 )
```

Comment: As an aside: It's not even necessary to create a variable, you can just add `+ ggsave(myfileme, width=7, height=5)`.